# Add github library as dependency in gradle

Tags: java, github, gradle

How to add library from github using gradle? I tried this and it didn't work. The library I want to use in my project is [XLLoop](https://github.com/poidasmith/xlloop). Here is a code from `build.gradle`.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.poidasmith.xlloop:xlloop:0.3.+'
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"..

Comment: From a quick review of the project page it doesn't look like any artifacts are published on Maven Central; so this is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XXLoop isn't published as a Maven or Ivy artifact so it isn't directly available to Gradle's dependency management.

You would download the JARs for XXLoop and define dependencies for it's dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    files('libs/xxloop_0.3.jar')
    compile 'something:xxloop-needs:0.1.2'
}
```

I've done this for a variety of things in production including the generated JARs for interacting with Salesforce or in-house libraries we don't have in an artifact repostory yet.